# AppEngine Email in Development Server

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

Where can we see the sent email messages in development server of Google App Engine.

Comment: in your inbox? what do you mean? did you start the SDK with sendmail enabled or did you use a google account to send mails out?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to start the dev server with options to enable email to be sent. You have a few options including specifying an SMTP server or using a local sendmail if you have it running. more here..

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Using_Mail

Answer (score 2):

If you don't hook up SMTP, you should see them in the logs.

Comment: you see that a message should have been sent but you cant see the message itself.